# Exact differential equation when both sides are not always equal?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Determine whether $\sin(y)\cos(x)+\cos(y)[\sin(y)-\sin(x)]\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=0$ is an exact D.E.

Define $M(x,y)=\sin(y)\cos(x)$ and $N(x,y)=\cos(y)[\sin(y)-\sin(x)]$
Then \begin{align}\frac{\mathrm dM}{\mathrm dy}&=\cos(y)\cos(x)\\
\frac{\mathrm dN}{\mathrm dx}&=-\cos(y)\cos(x)\end{align}

Which can be equal, but not always. They ask me for a general answer on whether the D.E. is exact, but I assume I can't conclude the D.E. is exact, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. Myb the problem further asks about *when* the equation is exact

(i.e. $\{(x,y)|\cos(x)\cos(y) = 0\}$)?

Also, I think you should say $$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$